# .NET WCF Service and $.ajax POST

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf

I'll try to keep it as simple as possible so feel free to ask for more details.

I have an application where I use jQuery 1.8.3 and the $.ajax method to post data... The ajax calls a .net wcf service ...

My application has a client-side console where I can log debug info into. So here's the js code:

```
    Console.WriteLine(Console.GetTime());
    xhr = jQuery.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: async,
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        processData: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        timeout: 600000,
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: AjaxSuccess,
        error: AjaxError
    });
```

The Ajax call work correct... The (Console.GetTime() justs formats the current time).

Both the server and client runs on the same machine...

I tried to dig through the code in order to find some performance issue.. For some reason, the function takes around 1100 milliseconds. On the server side, I proved it took less than 100 ms...

So here's my question... Why is there somekind of delay between the time I fire the $.ajax command the the beginning of the operation on the server? I compared both sides timestamp and there is always about 1000ms.... Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: is it only the first call that takes a second, or all calls?

Comment: on your client bindings try to set the following into max values maxDepth,maxStringContentLength,maxArrayLength,maxBytesPerRead, maxNameTableCharCount

Comment: It really depends... This partilcular one is the longer Erix. All others have different "delays" but not even close to a second.